# Routing not working after angular upgrade

Tags: html, angular, visual-studio-2013, angular2-routing, upgrade

I upgraded my angular project from 2 to 13 version and after that multiple tabs are not working properly[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vOhM.png)

Comment: Did you update from v2 straight to v13? Or did you go the recommended way one version at a time? https://update.angular.io

Answer (score 1):

In order to help you, we may need more information. But, from my experience, this is probably a problem with a deprecated package that doesnt work with newest angular versions. So, while upgrading to newer major angular versions:

1. Skipping major versions is not recommended.
2. You have to upgrade all third-party dependecies in your package.json to support the angular version that you are using. In order to do this, you should go to each corresponding library's documentation and read information about version compatibility.
3. Visit https://update.angular.io for more detailed information.